# Checking if an unknown class given by getClass() is a certain class

Tags: java

I have a type of Object variable called obj (Object obj). I'm using obj.getClass() and I want to check if the returned class is actually a certain class, in my case a class named Student. How do I do that?

I tried `obj.getClass().isInstance(Student)` but it tells me that Student cannot be resolved to a variable. Also yes I've done my research and have found similar questions on SO but for some reason nothing I've done works.

Comment: @Marv I'm using instanceof and it says Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#1-of ? extends Object> and Student

Comment: Try `obj instanceof Student`.

Comment: @Marv oh my god it worked. i spent two hours trying to solve this out and you did it in 2 minutes lol. thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to delete the question, as it's a duplicate and would probably be closed anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ‘Student.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())‘ or if you have the instance of the object just ‘obj instanceof Student‘.